# Jenkins when value equals sh output

Tags: jenkins

For a pipeline I want to execute a step, but only if the output of an sh command is equal to a given value:

What I tried:

```
def AB = "ab"
def CD = "cd"
```

In the pipeline:

```
stages {
       stage('Print working directory'){
            steps{
                script{
                    CD = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "ab"')
                }
            }
        }
        stage('AB') {
            steps {
                echo "${AB} == ${CD}"
            }
            when{
                expression{ AB == CD }
            }
        }
        stage('NOT AB') {
            steps {
                echo "${AB} != ${CD}"
            }
            when{
                expression{ AB != CD }
            }
```

However AB != CD is always triggered even though in the output I see:

```
ab != ab
```

So it seems like the value is set correctly with the sh output, but the compare is not working as expected.
What is the correct way to compare these two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use trim()

```
 sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "ab"').trim()
```

to remove trailing whitespace

Comment: Nice thank!, why is there a trailing white space. I would think echo "ab" would only return "ab" without an extra space.